# I want create a array List from the response below.My list should be of type Class Temp

Tags: java, android, kotlin

*In the key filed of TempClass, I want to add value like "RFI" and the respective open, close, overdue values of it on the remaining fields. How do I iterate through the response to create my desired list? The field names in the response like"RFI", "OBSERVATION", "SUBMITTALS", "SAFETY", "INSPECTION", "TASK", "WORKFLOW" are dynamic and can change in the future.The rest of the response remains the same. Please help.Response:*

```
     {
                "project_id": 1,
                "project_name": "Test Project R",
                "RFI": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 0,
                    "OVERDUE": 1
                },
                "OBSERVATION": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 0,
                    "OVERDUE": 0
                },
                "SUBMITTALS": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 0,
                    "OVERDUE": 1
                },
                "SAFETY": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 0,
                    "OVERDUE": 0
                },
                "INSPECTION": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 0,
                    "OVERDUE": 1
                },
                "TASK": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 0,
                    "OVERDUE": 0
                },
                "WORKFLOW": {
                    "OPEN": 0,
                    "CLOSE": 4,
                    "OVERDUE": 6
                }
            }

data class Temp(
        var key: String,
        var open: Int,
        var close: Int,
        var overDue: Int
)
```

Comment: Great! So what's the question?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve question quality. Edit your question to include source code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that can be compiled/tested. Check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see what questions you can ask. See: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)